# Running docker-compose container from docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, dockerhub

I have created 2 containers locally and pushed them into `docker hub` to use on a VM, one is an Angular App and the other is a Django REST API with a db:

#### Angular App

###### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install npm@8.11.0 --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/bom-e-barato /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I **created** the image by doing `docker build -t andreclerigo/bom_e_barato:latest .` then **pushed** it with `docker push andreclerigo/bom_e_barato:latest` and then I can **run** it on my VM by doing `docker run -d -p 80:80 andreclerigo/bom_e_barato:latest`

#### Django REST API

###### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.10
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /rest-api-scraper
WORKDIR /rest-api-scraper
ADD . /rest-api-scraper/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

###### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python backend/manage.py makemigrations && python backend/manage.py migrate && python backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: rest-api-scraper
    volumes:
      - .:/rest-api-scraper
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: andreclerigo/rest-api-scraper:latest
```

I **created** the image by doing `docker-compose build`, then I **pushed** it to docker hub by doing `docker-compose push` to **run** locally I can do `docker-compose up`

### Question

What steps do I need to take to pull this image and run the the image (`docker-compose up`) on my VM?

Comment: instead of `build: .` simply use `image: andreclerigo/bom_e_barato:latest`